# How do I get an exact / whole word only match in fullText from DriveApp.searchFiles in Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, exact-match

I want to search file contents in Google Drive for files that contain the word 'pass' - an exact match on the whole word 'pass'.

Currently I am using the following call:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('fullText contains \'pass\'');
```

I tried with double quotes as well...

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('fullText contains "pass"');
```

This was based on documentation I read here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters

However, both versions return files containing 'pass' as well as files containing derivatives of 'pass' such as 'password' or 'passing' etc. I tried to add white space to pass ('pass ' or ' pass ') but this seems to be discarded / ignored as well and I get the same results.

What must I do to get an exact match on the whole word 'pass' only?

Comment: Remember that `fullText` searches the _entire_ file, so if you're only checking the file name, the term must be in the file somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Brian, I've edited the question to be more specific in that searching the entire file contents is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Very strange. I've been poking and I'm seeing the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice where the apostrophe is placed:

```
 fullText contains '"Hello there"'
```

Just noticed this in the notes from [Search Files in Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

Comment: Thanks for prodding me to look closer noogui ... I thought I had tried that too. But it turns out that this is what I was looking for: var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('fullText contains \'"pass"\'');

Comment: You can actually post that as answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that noogui!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this is what I was looking for:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('fullText contains \'"pass"\'');
```